# Can't import classes from custom NuGet package

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget

I have a .NET Standard library with 1 interface and 1 class:

```
public interface ITestService
{
    void Test(string test);
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public void Test(string test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got this string: " + test);
    }
}
```

I published the library using Azure Pipelines (dotnet pack and dotnet push) into Azure Artifacts using a nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>Service.Client</id>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
    <title>Service Client</title>
    <authors>auth</authors>
    <owners>owner</owners>
    <projectUrl>https://dev.azure.com/yyy/</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>My test nuget description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Test release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>latest 5.0.2</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

When importing this library (successfully) into my other project, I can't see the ITestService/TestService through VS2019, even though I can see them in the nupkg!

Can someone help me import my library?

Comment: Did you increment the package version EVERY SINGLE TIME you published to your private NuGet feed? It sounds like a common scenario that you published the package without your new interface and class, used it on your local machine, then updated the package without changing the version. Now your computer thinks it has the package, without knowing it's not the same as the version now in your nuget feed. NuGet packages are by design immutable, so you must increment the version every time your publish the package.

Comment: Also, since your project targets netstandard, it must be an SDK style project. SDK style projects don't need a nuspec, you can specify [the metadata in the csproj file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target), or use Visual Studio's project properties window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using nuspec and the `nuget pack` command which didn't seem to work.
I switched using the csproj fields and Azure Devops to use `dotnet pack` command and it all works perfectly.

Thanks zivkan for the inspiration :)